# How to get the products that all Warehouse exist?

Tags: sql

I have a question as the title,I wanna get the products which appeared in every Warehouse,
I have no idea when i thought long time,i found i am so beetleheaded,

Thare are three tables in my sql server database:

Product
(
  productID,
  name,model,
  size,
  color
)

Warehouse
(
  warehouseID,
  name,
  address
)

Inventory
(
  warehouseID,
  productID,
  quantity
)

i hope someone help me to have a look and can write the sql that get the result

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a GROUP BY to count the number of warehouses each product is in. Accept those rows for which this count is equal to the total number of warehouses.

```
SELECT productID
FROM Inventory
WHERE quantity > 0
GROUP BY productID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse)
```

This assumes that (productID, warehouseID) is unique in the inventory table. If it is not then use `COUNT(DISTINCT warehouseID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.